# Как определить последнюю итерацию цикла for?

Tags: циклы

Часто бывает нужно определить последнюю итерацию цикла. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: всем спасибо. просто думал, что кто-нибудь сможет предложить варинт без проверки внутри каждой итерации.

Comment: Ха, после цикла добавь проверку!
А в цикле сделай переменную, которая будет постоянно увеличиваться, в конце цикла получишь число итераций.

Только это глупо. А внутри цикла это сделать проще + ко всему без проверки никак.

Comment: @Heleg

- А как по-вашему можно *определить* что-то, не проверяя?

- Формально можно расщепить итерируемую последовательность на `{0, N-1}` и `{N}` и выполнить для них разные действия, однако здесь тоже спрятана неявная проверка.

Comment: @Heleg то что вы предлагаете невозможно в принципе. Вдруг та итерация которую вы не проверили и есть последняя, как вы это узнаете?

Comment: я вижу выход только в использовании хвостовой рекурсии, т.к. условие завершение рекурсии и будет последней итерацией

Comment: А в некоторых языках (например perl) цикл for может быть сокращением foreach... И что Вы имели в виду под "как определить последнюю итерациею". Нельзя ли это выразить более конкретно?

Comment: @Heleg, «варинт без проверки внутри каждой итерации» противоречит самому принципу цикла `for`, где на каждой итерации а) проверяется условие, б) выполняется инкремент.
@Heleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Вычисление каждый раз

```
for (i = 0; i < m_i; last = ((++i + 1) === m_i)) {
  abc();
  if (last) efg();
  xyz();
}
```

Вычисление один раз

```
last = false;
for (i = 0; (i < m_i - 1) || (last = !last); i++) {
  abc();
  if (last) efg();
  xyz();
}
```

Разнесённая обработка

```
for (i = 0; i < m_i - 1; i++) {
  abc();
  xyz();
}
if (i < m_i) {
  abc();
  efg();
  xyz();
}
```

Редкий, но идеальный случай:

```
for (i = m_i - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  abc();
  if (!i) efg();
  xyz();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае - никак. Цикл for управляется предикатом, который теоретически может иметь любую внутреннюю логику. Однако если для переменной цикла возможно объявить функцию next(), которая будет возвращать следующее значение, то возможно сделать такой трюк (C++):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string::iterator next(string::iterator i) { return ++i; }

main() {
  string nums = "12345";
  for (string::iterator i = nums.begin(); i != nums.end(); ++i) {
    if (next(i) != nums.end())
      cout << *i << endl;
    else
      cout << *i << " (это последняя)" << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вычислить условие в самом теле.

```
for(инициализация; условие; инкремент)
{
    if (!условие)
   (выйти из цикла)
}
```

А еще можно сделать цикл бесконечным и выходить из него через if

```
#define ever ;;
for(ever)
{
if (условие выхода)
   (выйти из цикла)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во многих языках принцип одинаков: `for()` содержит три выражения, первое из которых выполняется в начале, второе выполняется перед итерацией, если возвращает TRUE, третье - после итерации. Можно прямо в этих выражениях узнавать, последняя ли итерация грядёт. Напр. на PHP:

```
for( $i=0; $i<=10; $last = $i++ == 10) {
    if( $last) {
        // последний раунд
    }
    // обычные действия
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А если не пытаться определять последнюю итерацию цикла, а сознательно "прыгнуть" в нее?

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
{
     System.out.println("For cycle iteration="+i);
}
//сознательно прыгаем в последнюю итерацию цикла
i--; //после завершения цикла i=n
System.out.println("Last iteration again"+i);
```